# Hibernate query invalid column name error

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

I am trying to get a query working within my application. The query runs fine in sqlDeveloper and brings back the expected data. When i run it through my application, it dies and i get the error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
```

this is the query itself - i have formatted the string for the query to make it more readable for this post

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<DataPoint> findEffectiveByNetworkObjectAndNameAndProduct(NetworkObject<Long> networkObject, String name, Product product, LocalDate date) {
        Query q = getSession().createSQLQuery(
            "select c1.ID, c1.NETWORK_OBJECT_ID, c1.NAME, c1.PRODUCT, c1.DESCRIPTION, c1.DATE_EFFECTIVE, c1.DATA_POINT_TYPE
                from DATA_POINT c1 
                where c1.NAME = :name
                and c1.PRODUCT = :product
                and c1.NETWORK_OBJECT_ID = :networkObject
                and c1.DATE_EFFECTIVE = 
                    (select max(c2.DATE_EFFECTIVE) 
                    from DATA_POINT c2 
                    where c2.NAME = c1.NAME 
                    and c2.PRODUCT = c1.PRODUCT 
                    and c2.NETWORK_OBJECT_ID = c1.NETWORK_OBJECT_ID 
                    and c2.DATE_EFFECTIVE <= :gasDay) 
                order by c1.ID
            ")
                .addEntity(AbstractDataPoint.class)
                .setParameter("name", name)
                .setParameter("gasDay", convertToDate(date))
                .setParameter("networkObject", networkObject)
                .setParameter("product", product.name().toString());
        
    
        List<DataPoint> compositionDataPoints = (List<DataPoint>) q.getResultList();

        return compositionDataPoints ;
    }
```

Here is the relevant mapping i have done

```
<hibernate-mapping default-access="field">
    <typedef name="Product" class="com.application.core.dao.hibernate.usertype.EnumUserType">
        <param name="enumClassName">com.application.data.domain.datapoint.Product</param>
    </typedef>
    <typedef name="Unit" class="com.application.core.dao.hibernate.usertype.EnumUserType">
        <param name="enumClassName">com.application.data.domain.measurement.Unit</param>
    </typedef>
    <class table="DATA_POINT" 
        name="com.application.data.domain.datapoint.AbstractDataPoint" 
        proxy="com.application.data.domain.datapoint.DataPoint"
        abstract="true"
    >
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="ID" precision="20" scale="0" not-null="true" />
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">DATA_POINT_ID_SEQ</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <discriminator column="DATA_POINT_TYPE" type="java.lang.String" />
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="NAME" length="64" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="product" type="Product">
            <column name="PRODUCT" length="16" not-null="false" />
        </property>
        <property name="description" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="DESCRIPTION" length="128" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <many-to-one name="networkObject" class="com.application.network.domain.AbstractNetworkObject">
            <column name="NETWORK_OBJECT_ID" not-null="false"/>
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="dateEffective" type="LocalDate">
            <column name="DATE_EFFECTIVE" not-null="true" />
        </property>
```

These are the exact column names in the corresponding table in oracle

`ID, NETWORK_OBJECT_ID, NAME, PRODUCT, DESCRIPTION, DATE_EFFECTIVE, DATA_POINT_TYPE`

I have also enabled tracing in my logging for more info on hibernate stuff = hoping it would give me the exact invalid column name but it doesnt.

You can see though, that 2 of the columns are not returned (PRODUCT and DATE_EFFECTIVE)

```
select c1.ID, c1.NETWORK_OBJECT_ID, c1.NAME, c1.PRODUCT, c1.DESCRIPTION, c1.DATE_EFFECTIVE, c1.DATA_POINT_TYPE from DATA_POINT c1 where c1.NAME = ? and c1.PRODUCT = ? and c1.NETWORK_OBJECT_ID = ? and c1.DATE_EFFECTIVE= (select max(c2.DATE_EFFECTIVE) from DATA_POINT c2 where c2.NAME = c1.NAME and c2.PRODUCT = c1.PRODUCT and c2.NETWORK_OBJECT_ID = c1.NETWORK_OBJECT_ID and c2.DATE_EFFECTIVE <= ?) order by c1.ID
binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [DAILY_COMPOSITION]
binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [GAS]
binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - [1]
binding parameter [4] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Sun Oct 01 00:00:00 UTC 2023]
extracted value ([ID] : [BIGINT]) - [10]
extracted value ([ID] : [BIGINT]) - [11]
extracted value ([DATA_POINT_TYPE] : [VARCHAR]) - [C2]
extracted value ([NAME] : [VARCHAR]) - [DAILY_COMPOSITION]
extracted value ([DESCRIPTION] : [VARCHAR]) - [BP Beachfield DAILY_COMPOSITION C2]
extracted value ([NETWORK_OBJECT_ID] : [BIGINT]) - [1]
Invalid column name
```

here is the full stacktrace - not sure if this is an oracle or hibernate issue as you can see there is the error `OracleStatement.getColumnIndex`

any more info needed, let me know

```
An error occurred during execution of handler: com.web.mvc.composition.ViewMonthlyGasDeliveryCompositionController#display(WebRequest, ViewMonthlyGasDeliveryCompositionSearchCriteria)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [select c1.ID, c1.NETWORK_OBJECT_ID, c1.NAME, c1.PRODUCT, c1.DESCRIPTION, c1.DATE_EFFECTIVE, c1.DATA_POINT_TYPE from DATA_POINT c1 where c1.NAME = ? and c1.PRODUCT = ? and c1.NETWORK_OBJECT_ID = ? and c1.DATE_EFFECTIVE= (select max(c2.DATE_EFFECTIVE) from DATA_POINT c2 where c2.NAME = c1.NAME and c2.PRODUCT = c1.PRODUCT and c2.NETWORK_OBJECT_ID = c1.NETWORK_OBJECT_ID and c2.DATE_EFFECTIVE <= ?) order by c1.ID]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17006]; could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:252)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateExceptionTranslator.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateExceptionTranslator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateExceptionTranslator.java:77)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:154)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy104.findEffectiveByNetworkObjectAndNameAndProduct(Unknown Source)
    at com.application.data.domain.datapoint.DataPointManagerImpl.getCompositionDataPoints(DataPointManagerImpl.java:43)
    at com.application.network.domain.AbstractNetworkObject.getCompositionDataPoints(AbstractNetworkObject.java:46)
    at com.application.network.domain.AbstractMeteredPoint.createMonthlyGasData(AbstractMeteredPoint.java:412)
    at com.application.composition.domain.CompositionDataRootImpl.getDeliveryPointTotalGasData(CompositionDataRootImpl.java:415)
    at com.service.composition.CompositionServiceImpl.getMonthlyTotalCommingledGasData_aroundBody68(CompositionServiceImpl.java:1263)
    at com.service.composition.CompositionServiceImpl$AjcClosure69.run(CompositionServiceImpl.java:1)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96cproceed(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:67)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect$AbstractTransactionAspect$1.proceedWithInvocation(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:73)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:71)
    at com.service.composition.CompositionServiceImpl.getMonthlyTotalCommingledGasData(CompositionServiceImpl.java:1252)
    at com.web.mvc.composition.ViewMonthlyGasDeliveryCompositionController.display(ViewMonthlyGasDeliveryCompositionController.java:122)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1043)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:529)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:152)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:156)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2871)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2682)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2677)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2186)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1204)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617)
    at com.application.data.dao.hibernate.CompositionDataPointHibernateDao.findEffectiveByNetworkObjectAndNameAndProduct(CompositionDataPointHibernateDao.java:55)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 93 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:3757)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.findColumn(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:264)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedResultSet.getString(GeneratedResultSet.java:594)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getString(DelegatingResultSet.java:263)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getString(DelegatingResultSet.java:263)
    at com.application.core.dao.hibernate.usertype.EnumUserType.nullSafeGet(EnumUserType.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeGet(CustomType.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.hydrate(ComponentType.java:670)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3214)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.hydrateEntityState(Loader.java:1811)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1784)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1624)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:748)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowsFromResultSet(Loader.java:1047)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:998)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:967)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2868)
    ... 110 more
```

EDITED:

decided to try and get some more info from the query. added `List results = query.list();`  - this returns an empty list. so it isnt even bringing anything back from the sql statement - does this give anyone an idea?

```
public List<CompositionDataPoint> findEffectiveByNetworkObjectAndNameAndProduct(NetworkObject<Long> networkObject, String name, Product product, LocalDate date) 
    { 
        SQLQuery query = (SQLQuery) getSession().getNamedQuery("findCompositionDataPointsApplicableOnDate")
            .setParameter("gasDay", convertToDate(date)) 
            .setParameter("name", name)
            .setParameter("product", product)
            .setParameter("networkObject", networkObject); 
        
        List results = query.list();
        log.info(results);
        
        return (List<CompositionDataPoint>) query.list(); 
     }
```

More of the DataPoint.hbm.xml file

```
        <property name="dateEffective" type="LocalDate">
            <column name="DATE_EFFECTIVE" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <subclass abstract="true"
            extends="com.application.data.domain.datapoint.AbstractDataPoint"
            name="com.application.data.domain.datapoint.AbstractNumericDataPoint"
            proxy="com.application.data.domain.datapoint.NumericDataPoint" 
        >
            <join table="DATA_POINT_NUMERIC">
                <key column="DATA_POINT_ID" />
                <component name="dataPointDetails">
                    <property name="unit" type="Unit">
                        <column name="UNIT" length="16" not-null="true" />
                    </property>
                    <property name="warningMinimum" type="RTNumber">
                        <column name="WARNING_MINIMUM" not-null="true" />
                    </property>
                    <property name="warningMaximum" type="RTNumber">
                        <column name="WARNING_MAXIMUM" not-null="true" />
                    </property>
                    <property name="failureMinimum" type="RTNumber">
                        <column name="FAILURE_MINIMUM" not-null="true" />
                    </property>
                    <property name="failureMaximum" type="RTNumber">
                        <column name="FAILURE_MAXIMUM" not-null="true" />
                    </property>
                </component>
            </join>
```

Comment: The first thing I notice is that you're trying to set values for a bunch of named parameters that do not actually appear in the query text.  Since your debug log seems to show parameters being successfully bound, I conclude that you have not shown us the code that is actually erroring.

Comment: ah my bad, i copied over the re-formatted query i was running in sql dev. thats it fixed now

Comment: Have you tried to use addRoot instead of addEntity? Just a wild guess.

Comment: @Grim added it and didnt work sadly

Comment: Just to be clear: do you confirm that entity-based access via the Hibernate session or a JPA EntityManager works correctly for entities mapped to this table?

Comment: @JohnBollinger yeah it works fine for other queries. It just happens to be this query that doesnt work. I managed to get it to run without errors but it brings back an empty list which isnt correct so not exactly much further - using a named query in my hbm.xml mapping - can post if youd like to see

Comment: You seem to be querying the table of a polymorphic entity hierarchy mapped using the single-table strategy.  Does the `SELECT` list contain all the columns that are mapped to *any* of the polymorphic entity classes involved?  Because the error message could indicate that an expected column is missing from the results, as opposed to one of those named in the query being wrong.  You need at least all the columns required by any of the concrete entity types that are actually selected.

Comment: there is a subclass `AbstractNumericDataPoint` which has the field private `DataPointDetails dataPointDetails;` - this is mapped in the xml mapping but it isnt a column in the table `DATA_POINT` - it is in another table `DATA_POINT_NUMERIC` - could this be causing the issue? i have updated the end of my post with more of the mapping xml file

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting entities from a polymorphic entity hierarchy that is mapped using the table-per-class strategy.  To do this successfully with a native SQL query you will need to properly (outer) join all the tables for all the classes in the whole polymorphic hierarchy.  Otherwise, your result set does not contain all the columns needed to construct the wanted result entities.

That could get pretty nasty if you have many classes in the hierarchy.  It's unclear, however, why you are writing this as an SQL query instead of an HQL query.  With HQL, Hibernate would construct the needed join and fill in all the needed column names for you. Something along these lines, for example:

```
        Query q = getSession().createQuery(
            "from DataPoint as p1
             where p1.name = :name
                 and p1.product = :product
                 and p1.networkObject.id = :networkObject
                 and p1.dateEffective = (
                     select max(p2.dateEffective) 
                     from DataPoint as p2 
                     where p2.name = :name 
                         and p2.product = :product 
                         and p2.networkObject.id = :networkObject 
                         and p2.dateEffective <= :gasDay
                 ) 
             order by p1.id")
                .setParameter("name", name)
                .setParameter("gasDay", convertToDate(date))
                .setParameter("networkObject", networkObject)
                .setParameter("product", product.name().toString());
    
        List<DataPoint> compositionDataPoints = (List<DataPoint>) q.getResultList();
```

That does make some assumptions about your entity classes and their mappings, so you may need to adjust it.

Also, Hibernate can do correlated subqueries, but you don't need one in this case because all the correlated columns are already constrained to specific values.  In the above example, therefore, I've converted your correlated subquery into an uncorrelated one.

Comment: Hey, this was really useful and did help but i ended up figuring out that i needed to have the proxy="..." attribute on my subclasses within the hbm.xml file.